# Preserve formatting for config file

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I need the following config file:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="ApplicationLauncher.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="OAuth2Service.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!-- Note that the paths can be entered on separate lines to ease readability
           but no spaces are allowed as this will cause any path after the space to be hidden -->
      <probing privatePath="Common;
Installed Providers\Messaging;
Installed Providers\CommonControls;
Installed Providers\DataManager"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <userSettings>
  <Messaging.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="IsMessagingFeatureOn" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
    </.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

And I want to update the value of:

```
<setting name="IsMessagingFeatureOn" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
</setting>
```

to false.
Here is the code that I use to change the value:

```
string settingsFilePath = "XtApplicationLauncher.exe.config";
            XmlDocument installerConfig = new XmlDocument();
            installerConfig.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            installerConfig.Load(settingsFilePath);
            try
            {
                XmlElement machineName = (XmlElement)installerConfig.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/userSettings/Messaging.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='IsMessagingFeatureOn']/value");
                if (machineName != null)
                {
                    machineName.InnerText = "False";
                }
                installerConfig.Save(settingsFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

The value is changed but the problem is that when I save the file the following characters are added:

```
&#xD;&#xA;
```

The file looks like:

```
<probing privatePath="Common;&#xD;&#xA;Installed Providers\Messaging;&#xD;&#xA;
```

This is driving me nuts. What can I do to write a clean file and to keep file formatting.

Comment: Your <probing  element has no terminator.

Comment: the tag is now closed

Answer (score 0):

`&#xD;&#xA;` are carriage returns and line feeds in XML, so if you want to write XML using `XMLDocument` with input like

```
<value>  
  3 
</value>
```

This will turn into

```
<value>&#xD;&#xA;3</value>
```

So Solution would be to update the input XML content without line breaks like

```
<value>3</value>.
```

In your case, it would be

```
<probing privatePath="Common;\Installed Providers\Messaging;Installed Providers\CommonControls;Installed Providers\DataManager;" />
```

Also, I saw your tag was not closed properly.